# freezing bkender when using soft body

Tags: soft-body

iam making a small scene using soft body on a sphere and its freezing my blender and moving 1 frame every 1 minute very strange even my pc is strong even when i use fire simulator also very slow and struggling to move 1 frame ! what

ryzen 7 3700X
RTX 2070 Super
32 GB Ram

What is the issue please ?

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are doing wrong is that you are not baking the animation first, no matter how powerful your computer is it will take time to bake and currently you are baking it while playback that's why you are not able to get high fps, bake the animation first and you'll be able to have a smooth playback.

Comment: thanks for replay i did it it improved but a little , ok another solution , doest it work if i saved the file first ?

Comment: The bake file is stored in a temporary folder you can change it, then it will be saved there until and unless you don't delete it.